# What extra benefit provided by spring's "@Valid" Validation annotation in contrast EJB validation

Tags: spring, ejb

Why do I have to use `@Valid` annotation in Spring, even when I create entity like:

```
public class MyEntity{

  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=5, max=16)
  private String username;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=5, max=25)
  private String password;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=2, max=30)
  private String firstName;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min=2, max=30)
  private String lastName;

  @NotNull
  @Email
  private String email;

  .......
}
```

In EJB I can just create an annotated Entity Class which automatically enforces validation constrains in web application. But why is this `@Valid` extra annotation needed in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

@valid is not an extra annotaion it is very useful when form binding,
for and example if you have a form which creates a MyEntity

```
<form modelAttribute="MyEntity">
```

and if user enters invalid data and submit the form without the  `@valid` annotaion

```
 ControllerMethod(@modelAttribute("MyEntity") MyEntity MyEntity){
 //you have a invalid object of MyEntity.      
 }
```

But if you go with `@valid` annotaion

```
    ControllerMethod(@valid @modelAttribute("MyEntity") MyEntity MyEntity,BindingResult result){
//with using @valid annotaion you dont have to check 
//if the fields are not null in the myentity object,
//if the myentity object does have errors or incomplete those errors will be stored in  
//the result object,so you can simply make a redirect to the form again
    if(result.hasErrors()){
    //object is invalid return to the form
    }else{
    //object is valid. you can continue
    }
    }
```

Comment: I want to know the comparison between the spring '@valid' annotation with embedded EJB validation. That is EJB validation work without '@valid' annotation but in the case of spring it required '@valid' annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In Case I want to send MyEntity class object with default field values then what should I do? Every time you may or may not validate fields whenever you want just use @Valid